# run python scripts in CMD much slower than in pycharm console

Tags: python, pycharm

I write a python script to do interpolation work. It will be called in Unity for simulation.

The problem is that when I run the program in PyCharm console, it only takes about 2ms.

But when I run this script in CMD like how Unity call python scripts, it takes 200-400ms.

the main code is as follows:

```
from time import time
start = time()
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interpn    

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 20)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, 20)
z = np.linspace(0, 10, 20)


def value_func(x, y, z):
    return 3*x*x * y + y - z + 100

points = (x, y, z)
values = value_func(*np.meshgrid(*points, indexing='ij'))

point_test = np.random.random([100, 3])
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
xt, yt, zt = np.meshgrid(t, t, t)
point = np.array([2.21, 3.12, 1.15])

result = interpn(points, values, point_test, method='linear')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    paras_output = result
    # print(paras_output)
    print('run time:' + str(time()-start))
```

Python version: 3.9.13
IDE: Pycharm

The simulation program need to call this python script frequently, the current runtime is not acceptable.

What should I do?

Comment: What the comand 'python.exe --version' says?

Comment: Python version: 3.9.13

Comment: Well, can you test with venv (https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and other version of Python?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?